# Why interact can't remain in ssh login status?

Tags: bash, expect, interactive

My login.exp script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -p 1111 root@vps_ip
expect "*password" {send "password_for_my_vps\n"}
interact
```

`expect login.exp` will enter into ssh and remain in ssh login status.

```
machine@local:~$ expect   login.exp
spawn ssh -p 1111 root@vps_ip
root@vps_ip's password: 
Last login: Mon Nov 12 06:32:28 2018
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Login into my vps and remain login status in my vps.

Change login.exp script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -p 1111 root@vps_ip  uptime
expect "*password" {send "password_for_my_vps\n"}
interact
```

The only difference is the last script has a `uptime` command for spawn.

```
machine@local:~$expect   /tmp/login.exp
spawn ssh -p 1111 root@vps_ip
root@vps_ip's password: 
02:19:33 up 7 days,  2:14,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
machine@local:~$
```

Login into my vps and execute `uptime` command ,then exit my vps,return to my local console.
The `interact` here can't remain it in my vps console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interact` would return when the *spawn*ed process finishes.

For `spawn ssh user@host uptime`, the *spawn*ed `ssh` command finishes when `uptime` (running on remote server) finishes, and then the `interact` would also return.

It's just like when you manually run the `ssh user@host uptime` which also would not give you the remote shell's prompt after `uptime` (and then `ssh`) finishes.